# How can I install a .so file generated from CMake and import it in python?

Tags: python, pip, .so

I tried these lines of code here in setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
setup (name = 'package_name',
       version = '0.1',
       author = "Nobody",
       description = """Install precompiled extension""",
       packages=[''],
       package_data={'': ['path_to_package/package_name.so']},
       )
```

And running `path/to/my/python -m pip install -e .` will say the package is installed successfully.
However I got module not found error when I tried to import the package.

So, is it possible to install .so in pip? If so, how should I modify the setup.py file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how do you try to import the .so library

Comment: I just did `from package import *`

Answer (score -1):

I think this will help you: [Building C and C++ Extensions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils)

Edit:
Just forget my first answer, you just have to name your package. That is fill in the empty strings on line 6 and 7. And you have to add the directory containing the .so file AFTER the install to the PYTHONPATH environment variable.